# Winforms OpenFileDialog problems

Tags: winforms, openfiledialog

I would like to create a file dialog form that works like the one in MS Word. Specifically, you can select an existing file, create a new one, or delete a file, all within the file dialogue window. OpenFileDialog is a read-only deal. You can't create a new file with that control. SaveFileDialog can't be used to select an existing file. Is there a control that will do all of the above?

Comment: OpenFileDialog is a sealed class. You cannot extend or modify it. So creating your own custom OpenFileDialog is a bit complex. You can start from here [Customizing OpenFileDialog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16276/Customizing-OpenFileDialog-in-NET)

Comment: Thanks, Steve. Was hoping that was not the case, obviously. I heard that Powershell Studio can do all the things that I asked. Pursuing that now. Appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 0):

To create your custom dialog you should follow these steps:

1. Create a new form, call it MyFolderDialog
2. In the new form add the controls you need. For example, in order to let the user browse the file system, you can add a treeView and populate it using the classes System.IO.FileInfo and System.IO.FolderInfo.
3. Create a property in your form that reflects the user choice, something like public string SelectedFolder
4. Add a "Confirm" button and a "Cancel" button to your form
5. In the cancel button click event handler add the code this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
6. In the confirm button click event handler add the code this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok;
7. Call your custom dialog like that

> ```
> private string PickAFolder() 
> {
>    string selectedFolder = string.Empty;
>    using(var f = new MyFolderDialog())
>    {
>       if(f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
>       {
>          selectedFolder = f.SelectedFolder;
>       }
>    }
>    return selectedFolder; 
> }
> ```
>
> Note that when the form is shown using ShowDialog method, the form won't dispose when it will be closed, so you can still read his properties after you confirmed. So it a good practice dispose it manually when you don't need it anymore. An elegant way to do it is to use the using keyword.

I hope this helps.